# ActiveMQ New build, latest version not working with latest Java

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am installing activemq on a new windows 2016 server. I have installed the latest version of Java "1.8.0_321" and the latest download of activemq "5.17.0", but when I try to start activemq I get this error:

```
Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/activemq/console/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-activemq-5.17.0\bin>
```

The JAVA_HOME variable is set:
[Java home variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5VY2.png)

When I run

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

I get

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_321\bin
```

From that I would infer that it is correct?

Any ideas please?

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? ActiveMQ is not compiled for java 8, but a later java version. Maybe there are other binaries available or it can be built from source for java 8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It states, on the [ActiveMQ home page](https://activemq.apache.org/), that ActiveMQ 5.17.0 release requires JDK 11+.

Your error message indicates the class [version number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) of Java 11, i.e. 55.

Either migrate your code to Java 11 or use ActiveMQ [5.16.4 release](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5016004-release) which is compatible with Java 8.

##### UPDATE (13 October 2023)

There are two versions of ActiveMQ

- Artemis
- Classic

As stated on the download page of both [Classic](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/) (version 5.18.2 at time of writing) and [Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) (2.3.1.0), both versions require minimum JDK 11. However, both download pages have links to past releases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what confused me was that I went to the 'Java' home page and downloaded what I thought was the latest version! it wasn't. When I now searched for 'Java 11', I found the Oracle page. It really doesn't help when people use different numbering systems!

Comment: For others that run into the same problem, the ActiveMQ home page no longer explains that 5.17.x requires Java 11.  However, it is now explained on their download page:  https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/